# What design pattern is best for highlighting a required user action?

Tags: gui-design

I have a summary page which documents a customers details. The customer is able to edit/change these details on a new page.

Upon returning back to the summary page they still need to submit the form before the changes will be saved.

**I need to find a good solution to let the customer know submitting the form is the required action to save their changes.**

I've looked at using a modal window - but I'm looking for a better solution which is more mobile friendly.

Comment: A save-button that pulls attention when something is being changed by growing bigger, wiggling,... Just a suggestion 

Comment: Do I understand correctly that customer changes details on detail page, closes detail page (NO SAVE), returns to updated summary page, and needs to save summary page before they leave summary page?Or do you want to save BEFORE user returns from detail page back to summary?  And are there multiple different detail pages (such as shipping info, invoice info, etc)?

Comment: Correct - Customer closes detail page (No SAVE) and returns to updated summary page, and needs to save summary before leaving. There are also multiple different detail pages.

Comment: Maybe I'm ignoring some other restriction you have, but why would you require users to manually save their changes? I would assume that they know what they are doing. Provide an "undo changes" button to guard against someone entering the wrong value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a sidebar that documents what changes have been made but not saved.  At the bottom of the list provide a submit or save button for the user to complete their changes.  Give this block(div) a little bit of a shadow so the user sees its above the rest of the page.  This block can be carried from page to page with a bit of JS.  When a user saves the changes, have the site notify the user all changes have been saved by prompting them in the block and emptying all saved entries.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You have a customer detail page, you send them to another page to make changes. When they are done, they come back to the details page to save their changes. What if they spot a mistake? Are they going to go back to the edit page and make changes again? Too much back and forth don't you think? Worse still what if they forget to save?

Actually nothing wrong with that, in fact I have seen a couple of apps with that kind of user flow. Personally I prefer to create a single page for the user to view and make changes directly. It is so much convenient. User hates filling forms, don't make their work more difficult than it already is.

#### Inline Editing

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxeWvn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You could also throw a dialog box to remind user of unsaved changes if they clicked on the back icon without saving.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an odd workflow but a bootstrap style alert with an action button placed at the top of the page perhaps.  This is where your user will be looking following the navigation.

Content should confirm the changes made on the previous page.

[image]